# How to use .setCurrentItem correctly? ViewPager example in BigNerdRanch series

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'm following the Android Programming Big Nerd Ranch Textbook.

Below is a section of code for a VIEWPAGER. I'm wondering why, if I put the following code in **position 1** vs **position 2**, one will execute correctly and the other will not. What's going on here specifically in terms of calling? This seems naive, but most of the time it seems like the code executes irrespective of positioning.

```
     //.setCurrentItem is meant to match the viewpager to the actual item 
     clicked in a previous listview - thus opening a fragment with correct 
     info populated.

     for (int i = 0; i < mCrimes.size(); i++) {
         if (mCrimes.get(i).getmId().equals(crimeId)) {
             mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
             break;
         }
     }
```

Correct behavior: Opens the fragment with correctly populated information

Incorrect behavior: Opens fragment with index (0) information

From my Activity which controls my ViewPager:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     //.... Some code removed for brevity...

     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

     //Position #1 The code does not work if I put it here - Opens a new 
     fragment with information from index 0 of my mCrimes array

     mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
         @Override
         public int getCount() {
             return mCrimes.size();
         }

         @Override
         public Fragment getItem(int position) {
             Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
             Log.d("CATS", "getItem: Called");
             return CrimeFragment.newInstance(crime.getmId());
          }
      });

    //Position #2 The code works if I put it here - Opening a new fragment 
    in with the correctly populated info from the index selected in the 
    previous list
 }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: And why do you think it's happening? First you are looping through crimes and trying to set the adapter position without giving the adapter to the viewpager.

Comment: Ah I see. So the order of code does matter for Java. It seems like a lot of the time with Java, that the code order isn't as critical. Perhaps this is only with regards to initializing classes? Thanks Ritesh